# What should I write in the brackets of this array?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, methods, parameters

In my constructor I set the array of bubbles to be the size of whatever is inputted in the parameter. For instance if the user enters "9" for the "numberOfBubbles", then an array of 9 bubble objects are created.

```
private double canvasWidth;
private double canvasHeight;
private Bubble[] bubbles;
int count;

public Mover(double width, double height, int numberOfBubbles) {
    canvasWidth = width;
    canvasHeight = height;
    bubbles = new Bubble[numberOfBubbles];

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfBubbles; i ++){

        bubbles[i] = new Bubble();
        bubbles[i].showBubble(width, height);

    }

    count = 1000;
} 

public void moveAllAndBounce() {


    for( int p = 0; p < count; p++ ){

           bubbles[].moveIt(); 

        }

}
```

In my method called "moveAllAndBounce", I want to move these 9 bubble objects around the screen in a for loop which will end once P = 1000, however I am not sure what to enter into the brackets [] to make this work because the size of the array gets initiated in the parameter of the constructor. If I write "bubbles[p]" this will not work because if I want the size of the array to be 9 in the constructor, then the loop will stop once p = 9. What do I write in the brackets to make this work?

Comment: Arrays have `length` property.

Comment: Depends mostly on what you're trying to do, which you haven't actually explained. If you're trying to move each bubble once, what's the relevance of `count`?

Comment: See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using `for-each-loop` which is internally converted into a regular `for-loop` and compiler takes care of checking the size of the array or collection (implementing Iterable).

```
public void moveAllAndBounce() {
  for (Bubble bubble : bubbles)
    for(int p=0; p<count; p++)
      bubble.moveIt(); 
}
```

Comment: omggg I love you, I've spent like 3 days trying to figure this out and your solution worked!

Comment: np, please accept the answer and vote up if it helped you resolved your problem!

Answer (score 2):

Your bubbles are numbered.  The first loop makes it clear that that numbering is between 0 and numberOfBubbles-1;

```
0, 1, 2, ..., numberOfBubbles-3, numberOfBubbles-2, numberOfBubbles-1
```

So, if you want to call `moveIt()` on the 5th bubble, that would be index 4, and you would write

```
bubbles[4].moveIt();
```

If you need to move all the bubbles, I suggest using a loop to `moveIt()` on each bubble individually.

Comment: But what if the user was to input an array of 100 bubble objects in the constructor? In the method would I have to manually write each bubbles[] up to 99?

Comment: @Matt.C You already use a loop to construct bubbles in your example.  So, you already have the answer to that question in your code.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to move every bubble 1000 times you can write something like that:

```
public void moveAllAndBounce() {
for( int p = 0; p < count; p++ ){
    for(int i=0; i<numberOfBubbles; i++){
       bubbles[i].moveIt(); 
    }
  }
}
```

if you want to have totally 1000 moveIt() function call, then in first for you have to change count to count/numberOfBubbles

Comment: I wish it was that easy, but numberOfBubbles isn't a global variable, it's just for the parameter for the constructor.

Comment: That's not a problem, you can also modify your moveAllAndBounce function and pass numberOfBubbles and cout to it. 

moveAllAndBounce(Int count, Int numberOfBubbles){...};

Answer (score 1):

All the array have a variable called `length`, and it can be accessed by `arr.length`.

In your case you have to build two cycles: one for bubbles, one for movement.

It should be something like:

```
public void moveAllAndBounce(){
  for (int i = 0; i < bubbles.length; i ++)
    for(int p = 0; p < count; p ++)
      bubbles[i].moveIt();
}
```

Comment: You can also use a for-each loop: `for(Bubble bubble : bubbles){ [...] }`